# How to Implement Record:<key,value> in Nestjs,graphql (code first method)?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

consider these types that are normally implemented in Typescript:

```
interface IProduct{
    normalPrice: number;
    salePrice: number;
}

type Usecase: 'best-selling'| 'top-view'

const UsecaseProduct:Record<UseCase, IProduct> ={
   best-selling:{ normalPrice: 10, salePrice: 8 },
   top-view:{ normalPrice: 12, salePrice: 9 }
}
```

we know that The implementation of interface in Nestjs and Graphql is like this:

```
@InterfaceType()
export abstract class IProduct{
    @Field(()=> Int)
    normalPrice:number;

    @Field(()=> Int)
    salePrice:number;
}
```

so how the Usecase and the UsecaseProduct should be implemented in Nestjs and graphql (code first method)?